# Where does sprintf store its output?

Tags: c, printf

If I have the following code, where does the sentence in `sprintf` get stored?

Is it stored in the 100 bytes `malloc` has provided or is it stored somewhere else and the `store` pointer now points to the new location?

```
char *store = malloc(100); 
int num = 77;
sprintf(store, "the number was: %d", num);
```

Comment: by "sentence" if you mean the output of sprintf, it is stored in the 100 bytes malloc has provided

Comment: @EdwardClements Yes I meant the string that sprintf will write into store. And thanks.

Comment: And be careful with buffers overflows, or use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: it is stored (if it can fit) on the store you give. Arguments in c are passed by value, so they cannot be changed by the called function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other answers here; let me just present how you can discover the answer to similar questions by yourself.

In C, arguments to functions are passed by value. That is, a function cannot change the value of its argument. This code

```
sprintf(store, /* whatever */);
```

cannot change the value of the pointer `store`, so it cannot make it point to somewhere else.

If a function has to change the value of a pointer, it has to receive a pointer-to-pointer instead. It happens that `sprintf` has just such a variant, called [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) (because it does allocate+sprintf):

```
int asprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...);
```

As you can see, its first parameter is a pointer-to-pointer, so it has the power to point the pointer to another place.

For reference, here is the declaration for `sprintf`:

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `asprintf` is a GNU extension, not a standard C or POSIX function.

Answer (score 5):

`sprintf` does not allocate memory on its own - it just stores its the input on a previously allocated buffer. In your case, this is indeed the buffer you allocated with the `malloc` call.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the 100 bytes that `malloc` has provided.